# Android DrawerLayout Lagging

Tags: android, performance, drawerlayout

The DrawerLayout  take noticeable time to close
here is my code:

```
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                   if (items.size() == 0)
                      view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   else view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
```

is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `onDrawerOpened()` method doesn't fire until the drawer is completely open. The perceived delay is due to the `View` being visible during the opening.

One solution would be to disable dragging the drawer, and only allow the toggle to open and close it. You could then do your size check before opening it programmatically. This, though, would require locking the drawer to the appropriate state in each of the `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()` methods, and, of course, you'd lose that standard mode of interaction.

The preferred option is probably to do the check and visibility setting as soon as possible as the drawer is starting to open. We can do this in the `onDrawerSlide()` method instead, keeping a `boolean` flag to determine if the drawer is sliding after having been closed. For example:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {
    private boolean opened;

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

        if (slideOffset == 0) {
            opened = false;
        }
        else {
            if (!opened) {
                opened = true;
                if (items.size() == 0) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you include

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
```

**What does syncState() exactly do?**

Well, ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState() will synchronize the changed icon's state, which deponds on actions of DrawerLayout. If you ever tried to remove the syncState(), you will realize that the icon of arrow won't rotate any more.

Comment: not wirking. you got the wrong idea my problem is not with the icon , my problem with the drawer layout itself it take time when execute code in onDrawerOpened

Comment: try to write  super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);  before 'hiding view' code

Comment: still no change